# Pattern calculus : Can I define function for data type with variadic number of type variables?

Tags: lambda-calculus

```
apply1 : (a -> b) ->           Foo a ->     b
apply2 : (a -> b -> c) ->      Bar a b ->   c
apply3 : (a -> b -> c -> d) -> Baz a b c -> d
```

As you see there is a repeating pattern, we obtain a function and a data structure, then we apply that function and return its result...

Is it possible to abstract over this pattern with Pattern Calculus?

How would the definition for generic `apply` look like?